# Could not cast value of type 'SPTSession' (0x110afab98) to 'SPTSession' (0x10f17f638)

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am using the Spotify iOS SDK and I am storing a session using `NSKeyedUnarchiver`

However the following code causes an error(some code omitted just for clarity's sake):

```
sptSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(sessionData as! NSData)
let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
auth.session = sptSession as! SPTSession
```

The last line of code is throwing the error `Could not cast value of type 'SPTSession' (0x110afab98) to 'SPTSession' (0x10f17f638).` I read that error as somehow there are two different types of `SPTSession`s but I'm not sure why or how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer seems to be related to this SO post:

[Swift only way to prevent NSKeyedUnarchiver.decodeObject crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904811/swift-only-way-to-prevent-nskeyedunarchiver-decodeobject-crash)

I have added an issue to the GH repo for Spotify's iOS SDK (https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues/759), and posted this temporary workaround as a comment on the issue:

for the time being, I have found a workaround - I can simply write `NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("SPTSession", for: SPTSession.self)` before I archive the session, and write `NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(SPTSession.self, forClassName: "SPTSession")` before unarchiving.

While this fixes the crash, I will leave the issue open as I am not sure if a change can be made in the underlying library to fix this